# FindAndModify with aggregation in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to combine aggregation and FindAndModify.

I have documents with the following structure:

- chat_id: int (not unique)
- flag: bool
- created_at: int (just timestamp)

I need a document by conditions  (minimum created_at AND flag=false) AND (there is no document with that chat_id and less created_at) => set flag=true and return

It is simple aggregation query: sort by created_at, group by chat_id with first by created, get first with flag=false.

How can I update and return the document after aggregation query?